# Errno 22 Invalid argument for file path

Tags: python, path

I'm very new to coding and have been trying to write some code to open a spreadsheet that contains URI links.  I want to iterate through the links, open the file (a PDF) and save each file to a new location.  When I use my code on a dummy spreadsheet with URI links that I've created everything works i.e it iterates through the rows, opens a PDF of interest and saves a copy to a new location.  When I run it on the real spreadsheet of interest I get an error.  The URI paths in my spreadsheet of interest looks strange to me in that the format is e.g. "file://///XXX/2016/Report 140428 2.pdf".  If I copy and paste that path into explorer it does open the file of interest.  Can anyone help me to understand what is going on please?  Thanks.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import shutil
 xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\me\summary.xlsx")
 df = pd.read_excel(xlsx,"Sheet1",engine=("openpyxl"))
 clean = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
 dedupe = clean.drop_duplicates(["File Size","File Name"])
 for index,row in dedupe.iterrows():
        source = (row["URI"])
        destination = (r"C:\my new path")
        dest = shutil.copy(source, destination) 
 print ("pdfs written")
```

Comment: Put the code in the question, using a code block so it will be formatted readably.

Comment: Python doesn't use URLs as file paths.

Comment: Thanks, first post so didn't even know how to add the code as a block!  Maybe I'm using the incorrect terminology - I think(!) I mean a file path not a URL.  The code works if I manually add my own file paths for each PDF into the source spreadsheet but it doesn't work on rows that start : file://///path/document.pdf

Comment: `file:` at the beginning makes it a URL. The pathname is just `/XXX/2016/Report 140428 2.pdf`

Comment: Thank you - I have no idea why but if I replace file:///// with \\xxx\2016 etc the file now reads in OK, using forward slash didn't work.  Thanks for your help.  I now just need to figure out how to replace file:///// with \\ in every row.